# RXJS: Optimal processing a particular event in an Observable stream

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am subscribing to an Observable stream of 'infinite' events ('infiniteObservable'). I want to do something special with event, for example #1, and then continue. There are two ways I can imagine. 1: using a boolean flag to find the event from the stream and set it as processed with a boolean and continue processing the stream. 2: Use two observable references to the same infiniteObservable and use one for normal processing and  the other use elementAt(1) to process the item of interest.

Is there a way to do this elegantly without booleans or counters or multiple Observers?

working sample code 1 below. Can this code be collapsed into one stream (without booleans?):

```
//current (non-elegant? uses boolean, etc) code:
infiniteObservable.subscribe((item) => {
  this.item = item;
  if (this.item && !boolItemFound) {
    // ... do some processing
    boolItemFound = true;
  }
});
```

I believe there must be a more elegant way using the powers of rxjs operators without resorting to booleans.  I have an alternative below which I find equally inelegant since it uses two references to the same infinitObservable (but no booleans). working sample code 2 below (can this be collapsed into a single stream?):

```
const normalInfiniteObservable  = infiniteObservable;
const firstInfiniteObservable= infiniteObservable;

normalInfiniteObservable .subscribe((item) => this.item = item); //process items normally

// meanwhile, grab item(1) from special processing
firstInfiniteObservable.elementAt(1).subscribe((item) => {
  // do something with item(1) only...
});
```

(NOTE: Although the above works, unit test/karma throws an **ArgumentOutOfRangeError**)
Any suggestions on how to combine the two streams above and avoid using a boolean as well (further above)?

Thoughts appreciated!

Comment: `and then continue.` - what do you mean?

Comment: @Maximus, edited and added details.

Answer (score 0):

If you need some special case handling,, and it should not edit the stream ( side effect ) you could zip the first stream emission with a range, this way you can have a single stream and an index, and do the logic for the Nth element.

```
// given a source observable 
src$.map( ( src, index ) => { src, index } )
.do(
    ( srcWithIndex ) => {
        //get index from zippedSrc.index
        // do write custom logic here
        if srcWithIndex.index == 3 [...]
    }
 )
// stream is not interrupted
```

Comment: My stream has 'infinite events' (edited), FYI.  I'm studying your response.

Comment: Sorry, i remembered that the map fn accept a second param which is the emitted index, i will edit my response soon